# How can I compile C# programs for Cygwin?

Tags: c#, cygwin

I know how to compile and run C++ programs from the Cygwin terminal using `g++`. What compiler can I use to compile C# programs for Cygwin?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to execute C# and .NET GUI in the Cygwin, you can try to check out [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19575/Building-Mono-on-Windows-the-final-battle) for details. It gives the full step-by-step guide on building Mono on Windows using Cygwin.

The build process is the same as described in the articles:

- Installing stable Mono for Windows
- Installing Cygwin
- Getting sources from SVN
- Building mono with mono in cygwin

Mono installation on windows https://github.com/mono/website/blob/gh-pages/docs/getting-started/install/windows/index.md

Comment: This website has detailed info. Thanks